# Read a csv file between 2 points

Tags: c#

I have a csv file and the beginning and end of this file is garbage that I dont need.

I am using ling to read the file

```
string startingline="start";
string endline="end";

var lines = File.ReadLines(myFile, Encoding.Default)
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToList();
```

Given that I have a start to read from and an end to read
how can I get only the text that is between these 2 lines?

Any Suggestions?

**UPDATED** with a sample of the document:

```
start

Name,Surname,City,Country

jo,Bloggs,London,Uk,

Name,Surname,City,Country


Mark,Smith,Paris,France,

end
```

I have no control over this document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to combine `Skip`/`SkipWhile` and `Take`/`TakeWhile`.

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("Path", Encoding.Default)
        .SkipWhile(l => l.Trim() != "start").Skip(1) 
        .TakeWhile(l => l.Trim() != "end")
        .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { "  " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        .ToList();
```

I've used `Skip(1)` behind `SkipWhile` to omit the line `"start"` because you want lines *between*.

Comment: You can try to use `SkipUntil(l => l.Trim() == "start")` without `.Skip(1)`.   `new[]{1,2,3,4}.SkipUntil(x => x == 2)` returns `3,4`. `SkipUntil` is from [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/SkipUntil.cs?r=ff61e76ceb312f5e9251739f80caef48173551d9)

Comment: @IlyaIvanov: imho there are better reasons for MoreLinq than that method. I find `Skip(1)` readable enough.

Comment: agree, there is a **huge** amount of nice reasons to use MoreLINQ. This is just a tiny one.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thank you that looks very neat and good.One more question if I can. unfortunately the headerRow appears multiple times in the original document,is there a way to get it only once,or do I have to loop through the lines and builder the header once and then skip it

Comment: @user231465: what means "get only once", what do you want to get? Are the `"start"` lines nested in each other?

Comment: I can may be build the header first and then I can skip all the headers .How can I skip all lines that matches my header?

Comment: @user231465: i still don't get it. Is the header the line "start", if not, is it before "start"?  Then i don't understand the question since `SkipWhile` already skips the header.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for your time I have updated the question with a noddy sample of how the document is structured

Comment: @user231465: what is the desired result? Do you know the header? Can you simply skip the header? For example: `Where(l=> l.Trim().Length > 0 && !l.Trim.Equals("Name,Surname,City,Country", StringComparsion.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: I can skip the header